# Add to latest child in tree array mode

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

Javascript code:

```
var data = [{
  name: 'hello',
  image: '',
  children: [{
    name: 'hello2',
    image: '',
    children: [{
      name: 'hello3',
      image: '',
      children: [{
        name: 'hello4',
        image: '',
        children: [{
          name: 'hello5',
          image: '',
          children: []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];
```

I want to add this array to last of the children

```
{
    name: 'hello6',
    image: '',
    children: []
}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far??? also share the expected output

Comment: @PranavCBalan
I thought failed

Comment: do you want to push it into the inner object?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using a [while loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'hello',
  image: '',
  children: [{
    name: 'hello2',
    image: '',
    children: [{
      name: 'hello3',
      image: '',
      children: [{
        name: 'hello4',
        image: '',
        children: [{
          name: 'hello5',
          image: '',
          children: []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];

// variable to store the inner object reference
var obj = data[0],
    // element to push the array
  ele = {
    name: 'hello6',
    image: '',
    children: []
  };

// iterate upto getting an empty children array object
while (obj.children.length) {
  // update reference to the inner object
  obj = obj.children[0];
}

// push it to the inner object property
obj.children.push(ele);

console.log(data);
```